# Date picker with MM/DD/YYYY format in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, react-datepicker

I went through the HTML5 input type date which accepts date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format. But my requirement is to accept date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

Also I came to know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

I went through [telerik date picker](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/placeholders/) which is as per my requirements and is a paid library but I want a free opensorced code/library for datepicker like in the above link which can accept in MM/DD/YYYY format, that has month, day, year blocks and has validations.

Comment: [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date): _"The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — **the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser**, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd."_

Comment: There are many open-source libraries which you can use. Most of the library accepts all the formats possible.

One popular library:
https://reactdatepicker.com/
@reciever

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker

Use this package,
scroll down and find the prop name
`format` and use it.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_